# what's the best way to prepare and share a playlist?

Tags: music, cross-platform, media-player, google-drive, spotify

i want to share a playlist with peers.  we're collaborating on a project.  the peer i'm working with presently has a mac.  i'm on kubuntu 20.04.  seems likely others might use windows.

some of the tracks have been shared to us on google drive.  some are on spotify.

what's the best way to prepare and share a playlist?  is there a cross platform app i can use to prepare the playlist?  and preferably play the tracks straight from google drive and from spotify?  i lean toward libre solutions when practical, so prefer not to just upload everything to spotify, is any other approach practical?

Comment: Have you check VLC Player, it is crossplatform and support playlists

Comment: i don't think vlc has a working ability to play a spotify song, i wish it did

Comment: I guess spotify can also play local files. Have you looked into adding them to a spotify playlist?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

- Use something like [mStream](https://mstream.io/) to "stream" the google drive etc. Then, you'd have the ability to share playlists. There are other similar ones like Plex/plexamp, Jellyfin, Navidrome, mpd etc., and various apps/clients.
- Use an app or desktop client that enables you to export playlists to formats like m3u, pls, etc. Then share the playlist via messaging or internet amongst yourselves. The playlist can then be imported on peers device.